# Does it gets faster than this?

Tags: c, number-theory

My current code for computing the legendre symbol is

```
inline int legendre(int pa, int pm){
    register unsigned int a = pa;
    register unsigned int m = pm;
    int t = 1;
    int tmp=0;
    while (a>1) {
        tmp=__builtin_ctz(a);//a=x*2^tmp, where x is odd
        a>>=tmp;
        if(tmp&1 &&((m&7)==3 || (m&7)==5))//if it is an odd power and m=3,5 mod 8
            t=-t;//invert result
        if((a&3)==3 && (m&3)==3)//if m=3 mod 4 and a=3 mod 4
            t=-t;//invert result
        m %= a;
        tmp=a;
        a=m;
        m=tmp;//exchange variables
    }
    if (m == 1) return t;
    return 0;
}
```

Is any optimisation possible here?

Comment: Possibly better suited on codereview.stackexchange , also - what language are you using? You might want to mention that (p.s. `inline` is pretty pointless right here in C, `register` too - compilers are clever enough to figure that out themselves)

Comment: I feel like you're showing off :D The code looks very optimized. Even if lets say switching the sign of the variable can be done faster, you won't get much performance out of it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum While inline had neglegible or no impact, register did. (from 3100 millisecs to 2350 millisecs calculating legendre(1...10000000,982451653))

Comment: are you looking to run it on 1950's machine? if not then whats the point in paranoid optimization :)

Comment: @Zia Actually, I will run it kind of a gazillion times in a math program, and it is the slowest part there. I may be crazy, but I dont feel paranoid right now :)

Comment: I -1'd. This question is not really SO material, the title says absolutely nothing about questions content and I daresay noone will ever benefit from it in the future (especially if this title stays as it is).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. It belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you know you need a lot of legendre symbols with the same pm, e.g: legendre(1...10000000,982451653)), you could compute them in different threads/processes, with one thread/process per core, e.g: a thread computes pa 1..2500000, the next 2500000..5000000, ... If you reuse the same legendre symbol (or if you can provide a recursive definition for at least some legendre symbols), maybe you could memoize them (cache the results of the function).

Comment: @ninjalj That was just a speed test, not that I need consecutive legendre symbols, or even on the same pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've already written, it looks like only fairly negligible optimizations can be made.

```
// Get rid of the inline, it's pointless for functions this large.
// Some compilers might remove the inline for big functions.
int legendre(int pa, int pm){

// Rather than creating variables here, you COULD make global
// variables and assign them here. That would get rid of some
// time taken creating these local variables.
register unsigned int a = pa;
register unsigned int m = pm;
int t = 1;
int tmp=0;
while (a>1) {
    tmp=__builtin_ctz(a);//a=x*2^tmp, where x is odd
    a>>=tmp;

    // This just throws both if-statements into one.
    if((tmp&1 &&((m&7)==3 || (m&7)==5))
       || ((a&3)==3 && (m&3)==3)) t = -t;
    m %= a;
    tmp=a;
    a=m;
    m=tmp;//exchange variables
}
if (m == 1) return t;
return 0; 
}
```

Aside from that, this code looks fine. I don't think you'll have to worry about it.

Comment: The `register` keyword is entirely pointless with any decent compiler

Answer (score 0):

The only possible thing that I could see can be optimized is the sign flipping:

```
t = (t ^ -1) + 1
```

or

```
t = ~t + 1; // I don't prefer this one
```

The funny thing is - it can be slower on some platforms, especially virtual machines, so you manually have to check.

**EDIT**:

OK, found a good thing that I overlooked, you create a temp variable to exchange them, you can use XOR for that, since they're both integers:

```
m = m^a;
a = a^m;
m = m^a;
```

that way the vars will exchange their values with no need for temp var

Comment: Have you checked that your optimisations actually improve things? I expect this to compile to the same machine code, because I expect the compiler to be fairly smart, but my expectations could be wrong.

Comment: Well, I did... but I'm an ActionScript programmer and our compiler is very stupid, so even making a variable name shorter helps. I'll be honest - I have no idea if C or other compilers do that. Besides, the question was about general code optimization, not how the compiler optimizes it, so cut me some slack and let me show off a little :D

Comment: There's no performance difference. The negation operator generates a NEG instruction on x86, since the CPU can do negation natively. It doesn't get any faster than that. Also, the XOR swap approach is slower and a bad idea. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm.

Comment: I just love to get busted, when I go wrong :) Thank you for the article, it was interesting to read it ;)